# log in based on roles from database

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

```
<label class="selecttype"> Select if you're an Electrician
    input type="checkbox" name="type_1" value="Electrician">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>




if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);
  $role_1 = isset($_POST['type_1']) ? $_POST['type_1'] : 'Homeowner';

  if (empty($username)) {
    array_push($errors, "Username is required");
  }
  if (empty($password)) {
    array_push($errors, "Password is required");
  }

  if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);


    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
      if($role_1 == 'Homeowner'){
        header('location: homeowner.php');
      }
      else{
        array_push($errors, "You're not an Electrician");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have to make user choose on a checkbox if they are an electrician or a homeowner. By default if the user don't check the "checkbox" it will detect as homeowner and is check in the database if its true. Else if the user check the "checkbox" and is not an electrician will send and error. if all are correct it will redirect to a page where they are designated. Example if user is electrician User will go to electrician dashboard, Electrician same goes to electrician dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have forgotten to ask a question.

If you are storing a role of Electrician or Homeowner in your users table why would you ask the user to select whether they are an electrician or not as part of the login? It makes no sense. Just perform login and redirect the user based on the role retrieved from the users table.

Your current code is horribly susceptible to [SQL Injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). You should be using [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) whenever you need to use user input in your SQL.

See [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify) for a better way to handle your passwords. A single MD5 of the password with no salt is definitely not adequate.

The example below is not intended to be a perfect example but it deals with the issues mentioned above. It uses PDO instead of mysqli, as I find it more intuitive. It assumes that your `users` table has at least the following structure -

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `email` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    `password` CHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    `role` ENUM('Electrician', 'Homeowner') NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE INDEX `uq_user_email` (`email`)
);
```

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

/* ENTER YOUR DB CREDS HERE */
$db_host = '';
$db_username = '';
$db_password = '';
$db_name = '';

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$db_name;host=$db_host", $db_username, $db_password);

$errors = [];
$email = null;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password', FILTER_DEFAULT);

    // I am not sure why I have left this in, but it's still here
    $role_1 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'type_1', FILTER_DEFAULT, ['options' => ['default' => 'Homeowner']]);

    if (empty($email)) {
        array_push($errors, 'Email is required');
    }
    if (empty($password)) {
        array_push($errors, 'Password is required');
    }

    if (empty($errors)) {
        // Here we are preparing and executing the statement.
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email');
        $stmt->execute([':email' => $email]);
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        if (count($result) === 1) {
            $user = $result[0];
            if (!password_verify($password, $user->password)) {
                array_push($errors, 'Login failed! Please try again.');
            } else {
                // do other login stuff here, like writing the user to session
                $_SESSION['user'] = $user;

                // your redirects based on the role read from users table
                if ($user->role === 'Homeowner'){
                    header('location: homeowner.php');
                    exit;
                }
                elseif ($user->role === 'Electrician') {
                    header('location: electrician.php');
                    exit;
                }
            }
        } else {
            array_push($errors, 'Login failed! Please try again.');
        }
    }
}

$errorStr = $errors ? '<div class="errors"><ul><li>' . implode('</li><li>', $errors) . '</li></ul></div>' : '';

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            label { display: block; }
            div.errors { border: 1px solid red; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            <label>
                Email:
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
            </label>
            <label>
                Password:
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="">
            </label>
            <label class="selecttype"> Select if you're an Electrician
                <input type="checkbox" name="type_1" value="Electrician">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
        <?php echo $errorStr; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this little snippet is to create a user with a compatible password hash -

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

/* ENTER YOUR DB CREDS HERE */
$db_host = '';
$db_username = '';
$db_password = '';
$db_name = '';

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$db_name;host=$db_host", $db_username, $db_password);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (`email`, `password`, `role`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$password = password_hash('mySup3R53cr3Tp455w0Rd', PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 12]);
$stmt->execute(['test@test.com', $password, 'Electrician']);
```